# How does the append function of a linked list update a nested node while overwriting the tail?

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I'm confused how `append()` is able to update a nested node in a linked list, despite overwriting `this.tail`.

How can `this.tail.next` update both `this.tail` and whatever `this.tail.next` is referencing, in the first case, `this.head`, and so forth? Especially when `this.tail` is overwritten to `newNode` right afterwards. Shouldn't that overwrite `this.head` entirely? How is the `next` key "saved" despite the entire `this.tail` being set to `newNode`?

Separately, I understand that `this.tail.next` is referencing the node before - but how does the references `next` key get updated if all we are doing is setting `this.tail.next`, and not its reference?

To illustrate this point - I set up a variable, `potatoes`, and another variable, `fish`, referencing `potatoes`. Despite updating `potatoes`, it is clear fish does not get updated as well, even though it is only a reference to `potatoes`.

```js
let potatoes = 5
let fish = potatoes
potatoes = 2
console.log(fish)
```

```js
class LinkedList {
  constructor(value) {
    this.head = {
      value,
      next: null
    }
    this.tail = this.head
    this.length = 1
  }
  append(value) {
    const newNode = {
      value,
      next: null
    }
    this.tail.next = newNode
    this.tail = newNode
    this.length++
    return this
  }
 }
 
const linkedList = new LinkedList(5)
linkedList.append(2)
linkedList.append(8)

console.log(linkedList)
```

Comment: But your 'proof' is using primitive values which aren't passed by reference. Try `let potatoes = {count: 5}; let fish = potatoes; potatoes.count = 2; console.log(fish.count);` see: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language#:~:text=JavaScript%20is%20always%20pass%2Dby,%2Dclass%20objects%20in%20JavaScript).)

Comment: Also, `tail.next` will always be set to `null`, except for the brief moment before a new tail is assigned when it will be set to point to the new tail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can `this.tail.next` update both `this.tail` and whatever `this.tail.next` is referencing, in the first case, `this.head`, and so forth?

`this.head` has a (deep) reference to `this.tail` via the `next` property chain. So when you mutate `this.tail.next`, then this change can be "seen" from any other node that has a `next` chain that eventually ends up at `this.tail`.

> Especially when `this.tail` is overwritten to `newNode` right afterwards. Shouldn't that overwrite `this.head` entirely?

No, *assigning* to `this.tail` does not affect the object that `this.tail` was referencing before that assignment. The only way to *alter* that object is to change the value of one of its *properties*.

> How is the next key "saved" despite the entire `this.tail` being set to `newNode`?

As said above, the object that `this.tail` referred to was not altered by this assignment. The assignment just "switches" `this.tail` to (reference) a different object.

> Separately, I understand that `this.tail.next` is referencing the node before - but how does the reference's `next` key get updated if all we are doing is setting `this.tail.next`, and not its reference?

When we do `this.tail.next = newNode` we *are* setting a reference to what `newNode` refers to. At that moment the linked list has become one node longer. When we then follow up with `this.tail = newNode` we make sure that `this.tail` references the *last* node in the list, which is an invariant we want to restore.

It may help to visualise the example you have presented in your script.

When `const linkedList = new LinkedList(5)` is executed, we set `this.head` to a new node, and we get this state:

```
 linkedList (this)
  ↓
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ head: ───────> │ value: 5  │
│           │    │ next: null│
└───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

The left box is the linked list instance, and the right box is the (first) Node instance.

The constructor continues with `this.tail = this.head`. This merely copies the reference to the new object into a new `tail` property:

```
 linkedList (this)
  ↓
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ head: ───────> │ value: 5  │
│ tail: ───────> │ next: null│
└───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

I skip the `length` property management here, as it is not relevant to the question.

Then `linkedList.append(2)` is executed. First `newNode` gets a reference to a new node which is for the moment is not related to the list in any way:

```
 linkedList (this)
  ↓
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ head: ───────> │ value: 5  │    │ value: 2  │
│ tail: ───────> │ next: null│    │ next: null│
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
                                    ↑
                                   newNode
```

...and this reference is assigned to `this.tail.next` as well:

```
 linkedList (this)
  ↓
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ head: ───────> │ value: 5  │    │ value: 2  │
│ tail: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next: null│
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
                                    ↑
                                   newNode
```

So the effect of `this.tail.next = newNode` is reflected by middle horizontal arrow. Note that indeed `newNode` and `this.tail.next` (if you follow the arrows) refer to the same node.

Now we execute `this.tail = newNode`. This is the (simple) effect of that:

```
 linkedList (this)
  ↓
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ head: ───────> │ value: 5  │    │ value: 2  │
│ tail: ──────┐  │ next: ───────> │ next: null│
└───────────┘ │  └───────────┘ ┌> └───────────┘
              └────────────────┘    ↑
                                   newNode
```

Note that with such an assignment mutates the linked list instance, but not any node instance. The `append` method finishes, and the `newNode` variable gets out of scope and is no longer relevant.

Let's continue with `linkedList.append(8)`. Again a `newNode` variable gets a reference to a new node:

```
 linkedList (this)
  ↓
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ head: ───────> │ value: 5  │    │ value: 2  │    │ value: 8  │
│ tail: ──────┐  │ next: ───────> │ next: null│    │ next: null│
└───────────┘ │  └───────────┘ ┌> └───────────┘    └───────────┘
              └────────────────┘                     ↑
                                                    newNode
```

...and again we mutate the node that `tail` is referring to with `this.tail.next = newNode`:

```
 linkedList (this)
  ↓
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ head: ───────> │ value: 5  │    │ value: 2  │    │ value: 8  │
│ tail: ──────┐  │ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next: null│
└───────────┘ │  └───────────┘ ┌> └───────────┘    └───────────┘
              └────────────────┘                     ↑
                                                    newNode
```

...and the only thing that remains is to let `tail` reference the *last* node (the invariant) with `this.tail.next = newNode`:

```
 linkedList (this)
  ↓
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ head: ───────> │ value: 5  │    │ value: 2  │    │ value: 8  │
│ tail: ──────┐  │ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next: null│
└───────────┘ │  └───────────┘    └───────────┘ ┌> └───────────┘
              └─────────────────────────────────┘    ↑
                                                    newNode
```

Hope this clarifies it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is why it changes both the `tail.next` and `tail` to the appended Node.

```
// This is setting the new Node to be the next Node to the tail Node.
this.tail.next = newNode

// Now it's setting the new node as the tail.
this.tail = newNode
```

To answer the reference question, In JavaScript only Arrays and Objects can be referenced, so in your pototoe example, it's not being referenced, but is assigning the value of the other variable.

```js
// Numbers, Strings and booleans, can't be referenced.
let potatoes = 5
let fish = potatoes
potatoes = 2
console.log("Number:", fish)

let orange = "5"
let raspberry = orange
orange = "2"
console.log("String:", raspberry)

let pineapple = false
let watermelon = pineapple
pineapple = true
console.log("Boolean:", watermelon)

// Arrays and Objects can.
let pear = [5]
let apple = pear
pear[0] = 2
console.log("Array:", apple[0])

let banana = {
  value: 5
}
let grape = banana
banana.value = 2
console.log("Object:", grape.value)
```

Comment: The curious thing about the question is that there is no referential magic happening. Just straightforward assignment.

Comment: There must be some referential stuff going on though - because this.tail.next is saved in this.head.next?

Comment: No, tail always points to null and no other node is tracking another nodes next. Though in this implementation when the length is 1 head and tail are the same node (still with next -> null ).

Comment: Yes, but we are seeing node.next saved in a linked list - when we set this.tail.next to newNode, is has to be updating something before this.tail gets set again to newNode, which has a next of null. Otherwise, .next would always point to null for any given node.

This is what I'm trying to figure out in the question - how does this.tail.next get "saved"?

Comment: @InspectorDanno I've updated it to answer the reference question too.

Comment: @Invizi so when we update this.tail.next to newNode in the first go around, this.head.next also gets updated to newNode (because of references), and then this.tail gets set to newNode?

Comment: @InspectorDanno Exactly.